# Admob Interstitial the ad does not appear, what is wrong?

Tags: java, android, admob

even putting the test id does not appear, I've made countless attempts, I found that it can be linked to mInterstitialAd.isLoaded (), but I can't solve it

I also tried to make modifications to the mInterstitialAd.setAdListener, nothing else happens, can someone help me?

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
                                      {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onAdClosed() {
                                              super.onAdClosed();
                                              doFunc();
                                          }
                                      }
        );
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }else
                {
                    doFunc();
                }
            }
        },5000);

    }

    private void doFunc() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: is it showing any kind of errors ? or just not showing ?

Comment: Can you please share your layout? Sometimes, the layout width and height needs to be adjusted to show the ad properly.

Comment: can you try code mInterstitialAd.show on button click and share logs?